# Response to GET method is 404 “Cannot GET” error

Tags: c#, angular

I try to learn angular I have a problem with CORS.

A create file proxyconfig.json

```
{
    "/api/*" : {
    "target": "http://localhost:9000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

9000 is a number of my backend proxy. Next, this file use in package.json

```
"name": "white-space-map-web-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Ofc is a part of this file.

I have a servise which gets clients from service.

This is my simple service.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Client } from 'src/models/client';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

    private url : string = '/api/Client';

    constructor(private http : HttpClient){}

    getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
       return this.http.get<Client[]>('/api/Client');
      }
}
```

Next I Inject in AppModule this service and use this method.

```
getClients(){
  this.client.getClients().subscribe(clients =>{
    console.log(clients);
  });
```

and HTML

```
<button (click)="getClients()">getClients</button>
```

All is ok but firstly i was a problem with protecion CORS "Access-Controll-Allow-Origin" but now i have problem because when i try click GET method I connect to the 4200 proxy and not the 9000, i.e. the proxy of my frontend and not the backend

[image]

This is my backend :

```
 public class Program
    {
       private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rc = HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service<OwinBootstrap>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new OwinBootstrap());
                    s.WhenStarted(owinBootstrap => owinBootstrap.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(owinBootstrap => owinBootstrap.Stop());
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();

                x.SetDescription("White space WebApi ");
                x.SetDisplayName("WhiteSpaceWebApi");
                x.SetServiceName("WhiteSpaceWebApi");
            });

            var exitCode = (int)Convert.ChangeType(rc, rc.GetTypeCode());
            Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;
        }
    }


internal class OwinBootstrap
    {
        private readonly IAppSettings _appSettings = new AppSettings();
        private IDisposable _webApi;

        public void Start()
        {
            var baseAdress = _appSettings.WebApiUri;
            _webApi = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAdress);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _webApi.Dispose();
        }


    }

 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder
                .UseNinjectMiddleware(new NinjectBootstrap().GetKernel)
                .UseNinjectWebApi(config);
        }
    }


internal interface IAppSettings
{
    string WebApiUri { get; }
}

internal class AppSettings : IAppSettings
{
    public string WebApiUri => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUri"];
}

 <appSettings>
    <add key="WebApiUri" value="http://localhost:9000/" />
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problems can be 3:

1. Have you ran **npm start after the configuration changes**?
2. Try changing your proxyconfig.json to this...

   {
   "/api" : {
   "target": "http://localhost:9000",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel": "debug"
   }
   }
3. your **/api/Client** might not be working, **try making a request with postman**

Comment: The problem was a npm start :) . I was a create a file but in terminal a wrote ng serve not npm start. Thanks.

Comment: @Błażej if it works for you, then please mark the answer as accepted. Glad to have helped :)